# Can I use Less to set a CSS background image based on a class name?

Tags: html, css, less

I have a template technology that generates my DOM and less generating my CSS. In my template, I am iterating over a list of objects that include a name for an icon image.

What I would like to do is take that icon image name and use it as a CSS class. Then with less, set the background image path to something based on that class name:

```
.className {background: url(../some/path/constant/[@className].png);}
```

..saving from me needing to set the background style in the template itself.

Comment: Then my HTML is nice and clean <div class="className"> whatever... </div>

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! Setting CSS background is not dependent on LESS. If you can do it using CSS, then you can always do it by less.

To set different background image (LESS way)

```
@image-base-url: "http://your-images-url.com";

.className1 {
    background-image: url("@{image-base-url}/image1.png");
 }
.className2 {
    background-image: url("@{image-base-url}/image2.png");
 }
.className3 {
    background-image: url("@{image-base-url}/image3.png");
 }
```

In your HTML:

```
<div class="className1>
      <span> This will have image1.png as background</span>
</div>
<div class="className2>
      <span> This will have image2.png as background</span>
</div>
<div class="className3>
      <span> This will have image3.png as background</span>
</div>
```